# POST запрос к стороннему серверу из iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, post

Есть сторонний сервер с проверкой данных из HTML формы - принимает text/html, UTF-8 
Авторизации нет, только капча.
Для отсылки на сервер jQuery-функция в родном коде страницы.
Обрабатывают отображение капчи и error'ы другие jQuery-функции.

Стоит ли формировать к серверу POST-запросы из нативного iOS-приложения (например, Alamofire.POST с параметрами) и сильно заморочиться с отдельным запросом .GET для отображения капчи и обработкой ответов/error'ов ("код не соответствует картинке" и тд) и ответа непосредственно сервера?

Или проще реализовать отсылку формы и обработку ответов через гибридное приложение с кастомизацией отображения формы при помощи инъекций JS (вроде бы на Ionic реализовали подобное приложение раньше)? 
Сейчас ковыряю WKWebView / Cordova / Ionic

Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Answer (score 1):

Проще добавить в приложение UIWebView, грузить урл и с помощью JS меняеть его форму (в методе делегата didFinishLoad).

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал.